# Make light independent from the view in a Phong model

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, lighting, phong

I'm trying to implement the Phong shading model, but I come across something quite strange. When I change the viewing position, it looks like the light behaves differently, as if it was dependent from the view. Like, if I'm close to the object I only see the effects of the ambient light, while if I go far away from it I start seeing the diffuse's contribution.

These are my shaders:

```
//Vertex Shader

attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vNormal;
varying vec3 N, L, E;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform vec4 lightPosition;

void main()
{
    vec3 pos = -(modelViewMatrix * vPosition).xyz;
    vec3 light = lightPosition.xyz;
    L = normalize(light - pos);
    E = -pos;
    N = normalize((modelViewMatrix * vNormal).xyz);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

```
//Fragment Shader

uniform vec4 ambientProduct;
uniform vec4 diffuseProduct;
uniform vec4 specularProduct;
uniform float shininess;
varying vec3 N, L, E;

void main()
{
    vec4 fColor;
    vec3 H = normalize(L + E);
    vec4 ambient = ambientProduct;
    float Kd = max(dot(L, N), 0.0);
    vec4 diffuse = Kd * diffuseProduct;
    float Ks = pow(max(dot(N, H), 0.0), shininess);
    vec4 specular = Ks * specularProduct;
    if (dot(L, N) < 0.0) {
        specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    fColor = ambient + diffuse + specular;
    fColor.a = 1.0;
    gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make the light behave independently from the viewer position?

### Update 1:

After @Rabbid76's answer I edited the vertex shader by adding these lines (as well as passing the separate model and view matrices but I'll omit that for brevity's sake):

```
    vec3 pos = (modelViewMatrix * vPosition).xyz;
    vec3 light = (viewMatrix * lightPosition).xyz;
```

And I also updated the calculation of the N vector as the previous way of doing it seemed to not actually allow a per-fragment shading:

```
    N = normalize(mat3(modelViewMatrix) * vNormal.xyz);
```

Still, the shade seems to move along with the rotation of the camera. This could be related to the fact that the light is multiplied by the viewMatrix I guess?

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-lighting-point.html) would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

The calculation of the light vector is wrong.

> ```c
> L = normalize(light - pos);
> ```

While `pos` is a position in view space, `light` is a position in world space. `light` is the position of the light in the world. So `light - pos` doesn't make any sense at all. Both vectors have to be related to the same reference systems.

Transform the position of the light source by the view matrix, before you set it to the uniform `lightPosition`, to solve the issue.

Of course the transformation can also be done in shader code:

```c
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform vec4 lightPosition;

void main()
{
    vec3 pos   = (modelViewMatrix * vPosition).xyz;
    vec3 light = (viewMatrix * lightPosition).xyz;
    L = normalize(light - pos);

    // ...
}
```

Further note that the position in view space has not to be inverted. It has to be

```c
vec3 pos = (modelViewMatrix * vPosition).xyz;
```

rather than

> ```c
> vec3 pos = -(modelViewMatrix * vPosition).xyz;
> ```

Comment: I still have some weird effects, the light still seems to rotate with the view

Comment: Note, the specular higjlight depends on the direction of view.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but the weird thing is that along with the specular highlight the shade moves as well with the direction of the view!

Comment: I've edited the question with these fixes and another one I made because without it I couldn't have a by-fragment shading

Comment: That was a bad idea, because my answer answers a question which isn'z there anymore

Comment: Gonna put the edits in a separate section then, sorry

Comment: Just did it. It almost works but there's one last detail bothering me there.

Comment: Is ligtPosition a view space or world space position?

Comment: World space position.

Comment: @memememe Again, the specular part has to rotate somhow with the view. Omly the diffuse part is static.

Comment: @memememe Kd depends on N and L, but Ks depends on N, L and V.

Comment: @memememe See [Lambertian diffuse](https://github.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/blob/master/documentation/light_lambertian_diffuse.md) respectively [Phong reflection](https://github.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/blob/master/documentation/light_phong.md). Possibly you're interested in an even more complex [light model](https://rabbid76.github.io/graphics-snippets/html/tools/light_model_view.html)

Comment: I've read them all but there is still something I don't get. In Phong, I have material and light coefficients for the 3 components of the light (ambient, diffuse, specular), and these coefficients regulate the color of each component (e.g. if a material has [1.0, 0.0, 0.0] as a specular component it will have a red specular highlight), but how do I regulate the *intensity* of the specular highlight? How do I, for instance, create a material that's only "diffuse", with no specular highlights at all?

Comment: @memememe *"How do I, for instance, create a material that's only "diffuse", with no specular highlights at all"* Set  (0, 0, 0, 0) to `specularProduct`

Comment: That makes sense but somehow I still have "moving shadows" even with the specular component at 0. I basically thought the artifact was due to the specular component of the ground's material moving when I rotated the camera, but it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

A working [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in your question is always helpful!

Issues

1. The light and the position need to be in the same space.

   Those could be world space or view space but they need to be the same space.

   The code had the position `E` in view space but the `lightPosition` in world space
2. You can't multiply a normal by a `modelViewMatrix`

   You need to remove the translation. You also potentially need to deal
   with scaling issues. See [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-lighting-directional.html)
3. The code is computing values in the vertex shader so they will be interpolated as they get passed to the fragment shader. That means they will no longer be unit vectors so you need to re-normalize them.
4. In computing the half vector you need to add their directions

   The code was adding L (the direction from the surface to the light) to the view position of the surface instead of the direction from the surface to the view.
5. In computing a surface to light direction that would be `light - pos` but the code was negating `pos`. Of course you also need `pos` to be negative for the surface to view direction `E`

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const m4 = twgl.m4;

const vs = `
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vNormal;
varying vec3 N, L, E;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform vec4 lightPosition;

void main()
{
    vec3 pos = (modelViewMatrix * vPosition).xyz;
    vec3 light = (viewMatrix * lightPosition).xyz;
    L = light - pos;
    E = -pos;
    N = mat3(modelViewMatrix) * vNormal.xyz;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vPosition;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision highp float;

uniform vec4 ambientProduct;
uniform vec4 diffuseProduct;
uniform vec4 specularProduct;
uniform float shininess;
varying vec3 N, L, E;

void main()
{
    vec4 fColor;
    vec3 normal = normalize(N);
    vec3 surfaceToLightDir = normalize(L);
    vec3 surfaceToViewDir = normalize(E);
    vec3 H = normalize(surfaceToLightDir + surfaceToViewDir);
    vec4 ambient = ambientProduct;
    float Kd = max(dot(surfaceToLightDir, normal), 0.0);
    vec4 diffuse = Kd * diffuseProduct;
    float Ks = pow(max(dot(normal, H), 0.0), shininess);
    vec4 specular = Ks * specularProduct;
    if (dot(surfaceToLightDir, normal) < 0.0) {
        specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    fColor = ambient + diffuse + specular;
    fColor.a = 1.0;
    gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
`;

// compiles shaders, links program, looks up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
const vertices = twgl.primitives.createSphereVertices(
    2, // radius
    8, // subdivision around
    6, // subdivisions down
);
// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  vPosition: vertices.position,
  vNormal: vertices.normal,
  indices: vertices.indices,
});

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds
  
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  const projectionMatrix = m4.perspective(
      60 * Math.PI / 180,  // field of view
      gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight,  // aspect
      0.1,  // znear
      100,  // zfar
  );
  
  const eye = [
    Math.sin(time) * 5, 
    3, 
    3 + Math.cos(time) * 5,
  ];
  const target = [0, 2, 3];
  const up = [0, 1, 0];
  const cameraMatrix = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
  const viewMatrix = m4.inverse(cameraMatrix);
  
  const worldMatrix = m4.translation([0, 2, 3]);
  
  const modelViewMatrix = m4.multiply(viewMatrix, worldMatrix);

  const uniforms = {
    viewMatrix,
    modelViewMatrix,
    projectionMatrix,
    lightPosition: [4, 3, 1, 1],
    ambientProduct: [0, 0, 0, 1], 
    diffuseProduct: [1, 1, 1, 1],
    specularProduct: [1, 1, 1, 1],
    shininess: 50,
  };

  // calls gl.uniformXXX
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);

  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
  
  // -- not important to answer --
  drawLightAndGrid(uniforms)  

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);

// -- ignore below this line. The only point is to give a frame
// of reference.
let gridBufferInfo;
function drawLightAndGrid(sphereUniforms) {
  if (!gridBufferInfo) {
    const vPosition = [];
    const s = 100;
    for (let x = -s; x <= s; x += 2) {
      vPosition.push(x, 0, -s);
      vPosition.push(x, 0,  s);
      vPosition.push(-s, 0, x);
      vPosition.push( s, 0, x);
    }
    gridBufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
      vPosition,
      vNormal: { value: [0, 0, 0], }
    });
  }
  
  const worldMatrix = m4.translation(sphereUniforms.lightPosition);
  m4.scale(worldMatrix, [0.1, 0.1, 0.1], worldMatrix);
  const uniforms = Object.assign({}, sphereUniforms, {
    modelViewMatrix: m4.multiply(sphereUniforms.viewMatrix, worldMatrix),
    ambientProduct: [1, 0, 0, 1],
    diffuseProduct: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    specularProduct: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  });
  
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, gridBufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    modelViewMatrix: sphereUniforms.viewMatrix,
    ambientProduct: [0, 0, 1, 1],
  });
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gridBufferInfo, gl.LINES);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

For me personally I find short cryptic variable names hard to follow but that's a personal preference.

Comment: *You can't multiply a normal by a modelViewMatrix. You need to remove the translation.*

May I ask you why? We have to somehow move the normals along with the object, don't we?

Comment: No, normals are only a direction. If you translate a cube 15 units in X the normals themselves all still point in the same directions. If you added +15 to each normal then normalized those left facing normals (-1,0,0) would now be right facing `normalize(-1 + 15, 0, 0) = 1,0,0`. One way to remove the translation is to take the upper 3x3 submatrix of the modelViewMatrix. Another is to set `normal.w` to 0 before multiplying. That still leaves the scaling issue. See [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-lighting-directional.html)